# Sample code to share a post on google plus and get comments of the post using google plus api

Tags: google-plus

I want to share a post on google plus and get comments using google+ api javascript code.Please send me sample code to share and get comments of the same post.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last share tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

also you can refer to **https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/**

Comment: i want to get google plus users commnets of the post what i shared.i know this